# Workbook cannot be expanded in OracleBI Discoverer

Tags: oracle, reporting, business-intelligence

I have a number of Oracle Discoverer workbooks which have become inaccessible to most users. These workbooks now only accessible to users with Discoverer administration access.

When regular users attempt to open the workbooks, they receive the error message:

```
This workbook cannot be expanded.
Unable to open workbook
```

A Metalink note suggests disabling fan-trap detection and disabling multiple join path detection. Upon making these changes, a different error is displayed:

```
Item "Folder.itemname" used by the workbook is missing. Would you like to continue?
```

After hitting OK multiple times and the errors have cycled through each item name in the report, I get to another ambiguous error:

```
Item dependency "" not found in the EUL. Attempt to open workbook failed.
```

I have also attempted to access them under a brand new user accounts as well as save the report under a new account/ re-share it with no success.

I am using the following versions:

- OracleBI Discoverer 10g (10.1.2.3) Oracle Business Intelligence
- Discoverer Plus 10g (10.1.2.55.26)
- End User Layer - 5.1.1.0.0.0
- Oracle Database 11g 11.1.0.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that an application had revoked roles assigned to Discoverer folders.

This was fixed by going into **OracleBI Discoverer Administrator** and clicking on **Tools** > **Security** > selecting the **Business Area -> User** tab

Under each business area was a role:

[image: eul role]
(Don't ask me what that icon is)

Granting each of the roles identified to the relevant users allowed them to access the business area. For example:

```
GRANT eul_role TO testuser;
```

Alternatively, you can grant access to business areas per individual instead of using roles.